# Understanding the proof that the graph of a function is homeomorphic to its domain

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, metric-spaces

[image]

I don't get the second last line of the proof. Why does phi being equal to the preimage of the projection map imply that phi is a continuous function?

Answer (score 1):

If a map  $f$ is open then its inverse $g$ is continuous: $g^{-1}(U)=f(U)$ for any open set $U$.

Answer (score 0):

The notation $\Pi^{-1}$ here means the inverse of the projection $\Pi$, not the pre-image.

The fact being used here is that for a bijection $f$, we have that $f$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}$ is an open map (so $f^{-1}$ sends open sets to open sets).