# Showing a surface is diffeomorphic to a plane

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I need to show that the surface $S:=\{(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R}^3:(x,y) \in A, z=f(x,y)\}$ with $f$ a smooth function, is diffeomorphic to the surface $S_0:=\{(x,y,0) \in \mathbb{R}^3:(x,y) \in A\}$.

I have done a lot of thinking but, since $f$ can be a non-injective funtion, I really do not know how I can find such parametrization.

Can anyone please give me a hint or show me a way I can think?

-Thank you

Comment: A similar question was posted recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4101676/42969.

Comment: What is the easiest way to map $S_0$ to $S$ or vice versa?

Comment: @MichałMiśkiewicz yes, I mean..that is exaclty my question. I was doing some reading on Covering spaces but I'm not sure how this can help.

Comment: I can take $\psi : S \to S_0$ defined by $\psi(x,y,f(x,y))=(x,y,0)$, which is clearly a bijective function. How do I find its inverse?

Comment: This is fine. And apparently its inverse maps $(x,y,0)$ to $(x,y,f(x,y))$, which also looks fine.

Comment: Oh thank you! Did not realize it was this straightforward!